# Picture will not change table td

Tags: html, html-table

I want to add table to my website that will not change height or width when I added a picture. The picture needed to automatic resize to td.
How can I do it?

```html
<table style="width:100%" border="1">
     <tr>
        <td style="width:34%"><!--Right-->
            <table border="1" style="width:100%">
                <tr>
                    <!--Symbol--><td>
                        <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right" style="font-size:72px"></i>
                    </td>
                    <!--Name--><td style="text-align:center"><b><font style="font-size:42px">dsfdsfs</font></b><br /><font style="font-size:32px">sdfdsdsf</font></td>
                    <!--logo--><td>

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td style="width:32%" rowspan="8"><!--center-->

        </td>
        <td style="width:34%"><!--Left-->
            <table border="1" style="width:100%">
                <tr>
                    <!--logo--><td></td>
                    <!--Name--><td style="text-align:center"><img src="images/company/integrity.png" /></td>
                    <!--Symbol--><td style="text-align:left">
                        <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left" style="font-size:72px; left:0"></i>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @dipak_pusti Remember to fix all the errors when editing: spelling, grammar, tags, typos. Just fixing indent is not sufficient! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use `max-width` and `max-height` and set it to size of `td` or `100%`

And I would like to suggest you NOT to write inline styles...

Comment: Not literally `td`

Comment: Width and height of td

Answer (score 0):

you using the % value to the table. So table are using current resolution i mean of the window in which you opened the page. In order to say for the table to stay in same height you need to use pixels for example:
570px; not 100% or 50% of the viewing screen.
so for the fist line i believe you can simple use the pixel value. 
for example:

```
 <table style="width:1200px" border="1">
```

for the image don't forget to add 100% values for example:

```
<td style="text-align:center" width="100%" height="100%"><img src="images/company/integrity.png" /></td>
```